# Is it possible to create UI for Ubuntu with HTML & CSS?

Tags: themes, html, css, environment

I would like to develop a myu own UI for ubuntu.But I wouldn't like complex C-coding to do that! Rather HTML & CSS are getting more powerful and we can even make a desktop class application with that. Is it possible to create UI for entire ubuntu(or Just a theme for Ubuntu) with HTML & CSS?

Comment: Do you want to build ubuntu app with HTML CSS ?

Comment: @orvi Yes! Now we can create Desktop app with HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT using wrappers such as _ app.js,Webkit wrapper_ . Can I make use of that to create UI for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You can develop using HTML + Javascript for the interface by using an embedded WebKit frame in a Gtk window (this is easiest to do in Python). The hardest part is communicating with the system from your HTML/Javascript application.

You can do this by passing messages between Javascript and Python. You will, however, have to write the system logic as Python functions but this is pretty easy to do.

For more details you can follow this link: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/apps/html-5/